# Suppose that A and B are mutually exclusive events for which $P(A) = 0.3$ and $P(B) = 0.5$

Tags: probability, self-study

Suppose that A and B are mutually exclusive events for which $P(A) = 0.3$ and $P(B) = 0.5$. What is the probability that

```
(a)  either A or B occurs? 
(b)  A occurs but B does not? 
(c)  both A and B occur?
```

Trying to understand how to solve this problem, I solved  (a) and got $0.15$ (by $0.3 \cdot0.5$) for the probability for either of them to occur. However, the back of my text stated the answer for the problem was

$\dfrac{3\cdot4\cdot4\cdot3}{{14 \choose 4}} = 0.1439$.

Could someone help explain to me what I'm doing wrong? This is my first stats class.

Comment: Welcome to CV! I would double-check your text for the question and answer. If the two are [mutually exclusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_exclusive_events), the answers are straight-forward: 0.8, 0.3, and 0. Is there anything more to the question?

Comment: No, there's nothing more :(. And thanks! I'm beginning to wonder if this is a typo in the text! The first chapter solutions lined up to the exercises but now I see that none of chapter 2's solutions line up.

Comment: Look up "mutually exclusive" and don't confuse it with "independent"!

Comment: Have you drawn a Venn diagram for these events?  In this diagram, polygonal areas (often circles) represent events.  "Mutually exclusive" means the areas for $A$ and $B$ do not overlap.  Looking at this diagram should make the answers to all three questions immediately obvious.

Comment: It is not uncommon to have mistakes in the answers given in the back of the book, and if none of the answers in Chapter 2 match up, I suspect that the author included some extra exercises in the latest edition of the book but forgot to update the list of answers in the back.

Comment: I just read a post on meta CV:"Are we seeing a dramatic drop in answers per question?". Someone suggested not to answer in comments. So, I posted an answer. I hope that's okay even though the answer was already given in the comments.

Answer (score 6):

To have mutually exclusive events means if one of those events occurs, the others cannot occur. Therefore, for the intersection of mutually exclusive events $A_\mathrm{i}$ with $\mathrm{i} \in \{1, \dots, \mathrm{n} \ | \ \mathrm{n} \in \mathbb{N}   \setminus  \{1\}  \}$ holds $\   \bigcap_1^n A_\mathrm{i} = \emptyset$. This implies $P[\bigcap_1^n A_\mathrm{i}] = P[\emptyset] = 0$. In general, the probability of the union of two events is $P[B\bigcup C] = P[B] + P[C] - P[B\bigcap C]$ . Hence, for mutually exclusive events holds $P[\bigcup_1^n A_\mathrm{i}] = \sum\limits_1^n P[A_i]$. Knowing this, you can apply it to your tasks:

a) $P[A\bigcup B] = P[A] + P[B] = 0.3 + 0.5 =0.8$

b) Occurence of A implies no occurence of B$ \implies P[A] = 0.3$

c) $P[A\bigcap B] = P[\emptyset] = 0$.

As already was suggested in the comments, the solutions in your textbook are not right and inappropriate for this kind of task.

Moreover, what you did in the calculation of a) was assuming $A$ and $B$ are independent and interpreting "either" as "and". Note, in probability theory, the term "or" indicates the union of events and the term "and" indicates the intersection. Therefore, it holds:

$P[A$ or $B] \ge P[A$ and $B]$ $ \iff $$P[A \cup B] \ge P[A \cap B]$.